# Can SharePoint search external web site?

Tags: sharepoint-server

We want to search a web site (not SharePoint site) on SharePoint 2019, is it possible? The web site could be searched in Internet by Bing, Google etc.

Comment: Do you try the following answer? If you have any updates about this issue, please feel free to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that.
You can create a content source using Web sites type, then type your external web site address in the "Start Address":

[image]

After that, start a full crawl for your external content type:
[image]